# Green lasers? I'm confused

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

There are green lasers in my world and they changed my sensitivity to default. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Green lasers?]

Comment: What does "and they changed my sensitivity to default" mean? Who are "they", and what sensitivity was changed to what default?

Comment: Also: you appear to be looking at a grid showing a chunk border. I can't recall off the top of my head which key it is or whether it looks exactly like this, but I believe NEI might be doing this. Check your NEI keybindings for the chunk-display feature.

Comment: F9 is the key that controls this

Comment: @Ender Want to write that up into a fuller answer? (I haven't been using FTB in months, so I'm not in a position to write a quality answer.)

Answer (score 8):

I don't know what to say about your sensitivity, but the green lasers as you say, are Chunk Borders and they are toggled on and off using the <kbd>F9</kbd> key.

Comment: If I could upvote edits, yours my good man, would receive one.

Answer (score 1):

You can toogle the cinematic mode with <kbd>F8</kbd> if you mean that with sensitivity.